# Center image background in table row

Tags: html, css, image, background, html-table

I would like to put an image in background of one table row, and i would like to center it.

In my project I tried all possible combination of:

background-position
background-origine
background-size
etc etc

But I went all the time with an non centered, stretched, non visible image.

I set up a plunker with an lightweight test application where the image is not even visible .... :

[Link to plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lRUlVKN0GAKh4aGQQZMW)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table class="table bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>col 1</th>
          <th>col 2</th>
          <th>col 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="loading">
          <td>val1</td>
          <td>val2</td>
          <td>val3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>val1</td>
          <td>val2</td>
          <td>val3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>val1</td>
          <td>val2</td>
          <td>val3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

style.css

/* Styles go here */

```
body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.loading {
  background: url('https://s9.postimg.org/7lhi0igcv/dotline.gif');
}
```

If you know how I can display this image at the center of my row, not stretched and with the background color as the rest of the page it will be a great help.

Comment: You need the background image on the tr or center of the table?

Comment: on the tr , i will use this, to display an preloader on a single row when the user double click on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```js
$(document).on('dblclick','tr',function(){
$(this).find('td').eq(1).toggleClass('loading');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.loading {
  background: url('https://s9.postimg.org/7lhi0igcv/dotline.gif');
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



    <table class="table bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>col 1</th>
          <th>col 2</th>
          <th>col 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>val1</td>
          <td>val2</td>
          <td>val3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>val1</td>
          <td>val2</td>
          <td>val3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>val1</td>
          <td>val2</td>
          <td>val3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: when you double click image will load

Comment: This is what you are looking? @Nicolas Pretot

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i'm looking. however it's strange because on my project : the background is not displayed. I will upload a plunker with the part of my project

Comment: ok you can accept the answer by clicking the tick mark and upvote.Glad to help @Nicolas Pretot.